# save/write data structure into binary file and then restore from it in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, char

I have a char** array that stores all sort of things like struct, integers and characters.

```
char** disk = new char*[100];
```

I set every block of disk to 64 bytes and use memcpy to store different information.

Then, I need to save this disk into a file, in which I can restore from it again.

But I don't know how to save this data structure into a binary file, all I know is output some text and read from this text.txt file using ifstream. I don't think this is efficient, so my question is what is the best way to write this disk into a file? How to write into a binary file? And how can I restore it (read from it?)? Could you please give me some examples?

Thanks!

Comment: why not `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`? Then you could basically do: `for(auto& a : vec) { ioBuffer.write(&a[0], a.size()); }`, since vector is guaranteed to be contiguous buffer, you can just force it to write it `a.size()` number of elements starting at the first element. Dont forget this is C++, not C, so you dont need to limit yourself to raw pointers, in fact you should not really use them unless really necessary(vector is basically a pointer anyways after optimizations).

Comment: `std::fstream` can [open files in binary mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) too.  Before worrying about "best way", try *any way*.  From the way this question is written, it looks like you haven't tried yet.

Comment: What about using a reasonable serialization library instead? E.g. like boost archive, or google protobuf.

Comment: To @πάνταῥεῖ's point, serialization of objects can be quite cumbersome, but on top of that problem, endianness can become an issue if you serialize your objects to a file without converting them to a specific endianness.  This is done so that when you deserialize your objects from a file, it doesn't matter what machine wrote the file out because you already know how the data is stored and can convert it to the endianness of machine that's deserializing it.  Serialization libraries take care of this for you, or provide utilities to do it easily.

Comment: @Creris That is a project requirement...